# Oracle Service Bus 11g - How to configure to get request's X-Forwarded-For header

Tags: apache, jmx, weblogic11g, osb

We have recently configured Apache Load Balancers in our domain via which HTTP requests are balanced and passed through to various OSB Web Services. The Apache LBs are configured with `ProxyPreserveHost On` which carries out the task of writing the client's IP Address into a new header `X-Forwarded-For`.

Our OSB Web Services then attempt to authenticate client requests based on the client's IP address as well as their supplied username/password. The problem is that when the OSB flows receive a new request, the `X-Forwarded-For` header is nowhere to be seen! With Tracing turned on, request look something like this:

```
 <con:transport>
    <con:uri>/ws/service/interface</con:uri>
    <con:mode>request-response</con:mode>
    <con:qualityOfService>best-effort</con:qualityOfService>
    <con:request xsi:type="http:HttpRequestMetaData" xmlns:http="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports/http" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <tran:headers xsi:type="http:HttpRequestHeaders" xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports">
        <http:Accept-Encoding>gzip,deflate</http:Accept-Encoding>
        <http:Connection>Keep-Alive</http:Connection>
        <http:Content-Length>1285</http:Content-Length>
        <http:Content-Type>text/xml;charset=UTF-8</http:Content-Type>
        <http:Host>www.a.service.com</http:Host>
        <http:SOAPAction>""</http:SOAPAction>
        <http:User-Agent>Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)</http:User-Agent>
      </tran:headers>
      <tran:encoding xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports">UTF-8</tran:encoding>
      <http:client-host>www.a.service.com</http:client-host>
      <http:client-address>xx.xxx.x.xxx</http:client-address>
      <http:http-method>POST</http:http-method>
    </con:request>
    <con:response xsi:type="http:HttpResponseMetaData" xmlns:http="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports/http" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <tran:headers xsi:type="http:HttpResponseHeaders" xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports">
        <http:Content-Type>text/xml</http:Content-Type>
      </tran:headers>
      <tran:response-code xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports">0</tran:response-code>
    </con:response>
  </con:transport>
```

The `client-host`|`client-address` values are that of the Apache LB and we are expecting the client's source IP address to appear under `trans:headers` in a user header - something like this:

`<tran:user-header name="X-Forwarded-For" value="yy.yy.yyy.yyy"/>`

I have read this link: http://www.javamonamour.org/2014/07/osb-and-load-balancer-source-ip.html but I'm not sure what exactly we need to do. I have connected to the Admin Server using `jconsole` and found the `WebServerMBean`'s `ClientIpHeader' (which is currently empty) but it is read-only and there is no setter for it. Any ideas what I need to do exactly in Weblogic OSB in order to retrieve`X-Forwarded-For` header from user requests?

Comment: Have you tested using `curl` or `soapui`, passing in the header manually and checking whether OSB can see it?

Comment: @TrentBartlem, I have tried your suggestion but still, the added header does not appear in the OSB flow's trace log. For my test, I've created a new Soap UI request and added in a header `'X-Forwarded-For'` with value '192.168.1.1' but it did not show in the OSB's trace log after sending in the request directly to the OSB Web Service in question.

Comment: Have you set `Get All Headers` on the proxy?

Comment: @TrentBartlem, setting "Get All Headers" on the Proxy Service solved the issue. We can now see the 'X-Forwarded-For' header okay. Please submit your suggestion as an answer to the question so that I can accept and close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless explicitly set, OSB does not parse incoming transport headers. There's an option 'Get All Headers' on the proxy itself; enabling that checkbox will allow them to be accessed inside the proxy.